# Shopware - Extjs - Can not send Ajax request from plugin config window

Tags: extjs, shopware

Shopware backend extjs question.

I have task to implement button on plugin config window which will send request on backend controller. So I implemented button:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygKJ9.png)

And wrote code to execute ajax:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shopware/shopware/5.3/engine/Shopware/Components/Plugin/schema/config.xsd">
    <elements>
        <element type="button">
            <name>Connect</name>
            <label lang="de">Verbinde</label>
            <label lang="en">Connect</label>
            <options>
                <handler>
                    <![CDATA[
                        function () {
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                method: 'POST',
                                url: 'UserData/getTokens',
                                params: {
                                    request: 'request'
                                },
                                success: function (res) {
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    ]]>
                </handler>
            </options>
        </element>
    </elements>
</config>
```

And when I click to button I get status 500 with message in apache log:

Call to undefined method Shopware_Proxies_ShopwareControllersBackendEtsyUserDataProxy::setFront()

So, is there proper way to write this request or I misunderstood something?
Or it is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

i think it is a bug, could you provide me with your controller file
I think you have to add this line at the top of your action getTokens

```
<?php

namespace PluginName\Controller\Backend;

class UserData extends \Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs
{
    public function getTokensAction()
    {
         $this->container->get('front')->Plugins()->ViewRenderer()->setNoRender();
.........................
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).